# Opening Bootstrap Alert programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session-storage, alerts

I'm trying to dynamically show a bootstrap alert https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/alerts/
that displays a message to accept using cookies once a user clicks the OK button, the alert message should disappear and not show to that user again during that session.

Unfortunately, I can't find a documentation on bootstrap site that allows for programmatic opening of a bootstrap alert. Therefore every-time the website is refreshed, the alert pops up again.

```
 <div class="alert fade show cookie-alert" role="alert" data-dismiss="alert">
            <div class="container">
                This website stores cookies. These cookies are used to collect information about how you interact with our website, we use this information to improve and customize your browsing experience. Read our <a target="_blank" href="http://assets.investnow.ng/InvestNow_TC.pdf" style="color:gray;font-weight:bold">terms and conditions</a> to learn more.
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right cookie-btn okbtn" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't open the alert, I already tried that.

Comment: I've added the HTML snippet i'm using to the question.

Comment: As you said, it's a "bootstrap alert", not a "modal" (slightly confusing as you say "opening of an alert", which makes no sense as you don't "open" an alert, you "open" a dialog).   You can simply not show the alert, then only show it when needed.   `<div class='alert` style='display:none;'`  `if (showalert) $(".alert").slideDown()`.   You can also use inline javascript with document.write to only output the alert when required, but most people would suggest against that.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="alert  alert-dismissible">
    <div class="container">
                This website stores cookies. These cookies are used to collect information about how you interact with our website, we use this information to improve and customize your browsing experience. Read our <a target="_blank" href="http://assets.investnow.ng/InvestNow_TC.pdf" style="color:gray;font-weight:bold">terms and conditions</a> to learn more.
                <button type="button" id="alertClose" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right cookie-btn okbtn" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">OK</button>
            </div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
localStorage.setItem("acceptCookies", true);
 $(".alert").hide();
 if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  if (localStorage.getItem("acceptCookies")) {
    $(".alert").show();
    $("#alertClose").click(function(){
      localStorage.setItem("acceptCookies", "accepted");
      $(".alert").alert("close");
    });
  }
 } 
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @chans, It solves the problem if I was using a modal but I'm using an alert and  as such, $("#alert").show() won't work. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/alerts/
doesn't show how to trigger an alert with JS 
$('.alert').alert()
doesn't work either.

Comment: I've added the HTML snippet i'm using to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could store in localStorage if the user has dismissed the cookie alert.

On page load, you would check if the key has ben set and show the alert if not:

```js
if (!localStorage.getItem('cookie-alert-dismissed')) {
    $('#cookie-alert').show()
}
```

and then add it when the user closes the alert:

```js
$('#cookie-alert button').click(function() {
    $('#cookie-alert').hide()
    localStorage.setItem('cookie-alert-dismissed', 1);
});
```

This key would persist until the user empties their localStorage or uses a different browser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... it partially solves the problem but again, I haven't found a way to actually do  $('#cookie-alert').show() on bootstrap alerts here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/alerts/

Note: I'm not using a modal but an alert.

Comment: I've added the HTML snippet i'm using to the question.